# self variables not being stored in python?

Tags: python, variables, global, self

I'm declaring self variables in my program regularly:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.x = dict()
```

And later on in my code (the first function that is called), I assigned a value to self.x.
However later on when I try to actually use self.x in later functions, self.x prints out as {}. Even though I know for sure that I am assigning it correctly and that my data is sound.

Bit of a python noob here, is there anything I may be missing? Should I declare these variables as global since maybe I am losing scope in the way my program is written?

Thanks

Comment: dict() is the same thing as {}. What's the problem?

Comment: `dict()` is equivalent to `{}`.

Comment: `dict()` instantiates an empty dictionary, and the literal form of empty dictionaries is `{}`. Everything seems to be working as you intended.

Comment: Can you show the function with which you "assigned a value to `self.x`"?

Comment: @A.R.S., that would be `__init__()`, which is in the question, I think.

Comment: The OP mentions that he reassigns/modifies `self.x` later on, right?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I assume the OP means (s)he does something like ``self.x["foo"] = "bar"``.

Comment: @A.R.S., Jonas, you're right, I missed the first `later on`. My bad.

Comment: post complete, minimal code with expected and actual results

Comment: is `__init__` defined inside a class? if not; it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without seeing the rest of your code (I will edit this post when you give more information), but maybe I can give you some insight into what might be the problem. Your functions should probably look something like those shown in the class below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = dict()

    def add(self):
        self.x[1] = 'a'  # add something to our dict

    def redefine(self):
        self.x = {2:'b', 3:'c'}  # reassign our dict
```

So to see that everything is in order:

```
foo = Foo()
print foo.x
foo.add()
print foo.x
foo.redefine()
print foo.x
```

Output:

> {}
>   {1: 'a'}
>   {2: 'b', 3: 'c'}